# Remove all the strings out of specific tag in bash

Tags: regex, bash

Suppose I have this file:

```
this is 1th line
this is 2th line
<<EOM
this is 3th line
EOM>>
this is 4th line
<<EOM
this is 5th line
EOM>>
this is 6th line
```

Is there anyway to run a command in bash to get:

```
this is 3th line
this is 5th line
```

and get the full text when there's no `<<EOM` on it?

Comment: Can you decribe the logic? It's not clear why the 3**rd** and 5th lines were selected.

Comment: The question is unclear. Is that an example input or the actual input? Do you want to remove lines containing a specific pattern and afterwards extract the 3rd and 5th lines, regardless of their content?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work:

```
$ sed -n '/<<EOM/,/EOM>>/p' file | grep -v EOM || cat file
```

I mean...

1. It should print lines between EOM markers **if** they are present
   or:
2. print the whole file if EOMs are not there

And... this is better (avoid removing lines between markers containing EOM):

```
$ sed -n '/<<EOM/,/EOM>>/p' file | grep -vw '<<EOM\|EOM>>' || cat file
```

Comment: `sed '/<<EOM/,/EOM>>/{//!p};d'`

Comment: @123 yes I agree, this is more elegant and avoids piping to grep. But... we have to print either lines between EOM markers OR the whole file when the EOM markers are not present. I decided to pipe EOM markers to grep by intention in order to have `|| cat file` at the end.

Comment: `sed '1h;1!H;/<<EOM/,/EOM>>/{//!p};${x;//!p};d'`

Comment: @123 This is better. Good job

Answer (score 2):

```
grep -q "<<EOM" file && awk '/<<EOM/{flag=1;next}/EOM>>/{flag=0}flag' file || cat file
```

if `<<EOM` is found in `file` it will print the lines between `<<EOM` and `EOM>>` with `awk`. Else just `cat` the `file`

Comment: Have to be careful with the `A && B || C` idiom: if A succeeds but B fails, C *will* run. You probably want `if A; then B; else C; fi` here.